# Good abstraction for interacting with a Restful service in Scala?

Tags: scala, rest, database-schema, dsl, case-class

I want to create objects that represent the data structures that are passed back and forth to a Restful service.

1. There must be an obvious and direct relationship between the record as documented in the service, and the record as interacted with in the Scala code, e.g. `obj.id` means the `id` field of the object.
2. I'd like to be able to define what fields make up the record in a declarative way.
3. For each field, I'd like to be able to also declare attributes like required/optional, unique, data type, max length, min/max values, default values, etc, much like the definition of a table in SQL
4. `obj.json` returns the object serialized as a string in JSON format
5. `TypeCompanionObject.fromJson` returns an `obj` from the JSON string
6. I want to be able to define generic test cases that can be applied to any field of type String, or to any field that is marked Required, etc.

I initially tried using a simple case class and Genson to do the serialization and de-serialization.  That took care of requirements 1, 2, 4, and 5.  But it didn't really let me do 3 or 6.

What's a good pattern that will meet all of my requirements?

Comment: Questions asking for third party libraries are off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think 3 and 6 should be part of a json databinding lib. The easiest solution for 3 would be to hook in your `fromJson` some kind of validation over the deserialized object. The validation could be implemented, inside the companion object of your cases classes or in some validate method implemented by the case classes, without going the route of something super fancy and generic. Of course you can plug there some generic lib if you prefer.

There are other options where you could directly plug in your validation in Genson. But this sounds unnecessary to me.

Comment: If all I wanted was a library for data binding, then my original solution would work.  3 and 6 are for me to describe the characteristics of the service, so I can then pull in test cases easily.  For example,  if I declare that a field is 'optional' then a test case is automatically generated to test what happens if the field is not present.  If I mark it as 'readOnly' then another test tries to update the field and verifies that the update fails, and so on.

Comment: Basically, I will define a bunch of common/reusable test cases, and then by simply annotating the class (or its companion object), there is a succinct and declarative way of indicating which of the standard tests to apply.

Comment: If there's a better way of doing that, I'd love suggestions.

Comment: I understand but I don't know of any library that will do all that for you in scala. The closest that does the validation would be java bean validation but it doesn't play nicely with scala. My point is that as you already add an abstraction layer on top of the deser, you can plug there your validation system. If you decide to go with annotations, Genson can expose those annotations to you, however you will have to use some of the more advanced API of Genson.

Comment: I'm not looking for a library, necessarily.  I'm looking for ideas of how to write code that meets all of my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I could try to reach 3 by adding some custom annotations to fields. I don't know for sure, but I have some confidence that json serializers/desiralizers should be able to pick those annotations, so you will be able to check them at the runtime. I think that some variation of the given approach may help you to solve 6. And I would agree with eugen, that you may find something like it in databinding library

```
case class Person(
  @Required name: @Required String, age: Int, @Optional gender: Gender
)
```